# exponential in SQLite3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm wrting a python code that creates a SQLite database and does some calculations for massive tables. To begin with, reason i'm doing it in SQLite through python is memory, my data is huge that will break into a memory error if run in, say, pandas. and if chuncked it'll take ages, generally because pandas is slow with merges and groupes, etc.

So my issue now is at some point, i want to calculate exponential of one column in a table (sample code below) but it seems that SQLite doesn't have an EXP function.

I can write data to a dataframe and then use numpy to calculate the EXP but that then beats the whole point that pushed my twoards DBs and not have the additional time of reading/writing back and forth between the DB and python.

so my question is this: is there a way around this to calculate the exponential within the database? i've read that i can create the function within sqlite3 in python, but i have no idea how. If you know how or can direct me to where i can find relavent info then i would be thankful, thanks.

Sample of my code where i'm trying to do the calculation, note here i'm just providing a sample where the table is coming directly from a csv, but in my process it's actually created within the DB after lots of megres and group bys:

```
import sqlite3

#set path and files names
folderPath = 'C:\\SCP\\'
inputDemandFile = 'demandFile.csv'

#set connection to database
conn = sqlite3.connect(folderPath + dataBaseName)
cur = conn.cursor()

#read demand file into db
inputDemand = pd.read_csv(folderPath + inputDemandFile)
inputDemand.to_sql('inputDemand', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

#create new table and calculate EXP
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE demand_exp AS SELECT from_zone_id, to_zone_id, EXP(demand) AS EXP_Demand FROM inputDemand;')
```

Comment: Did you try it with python? there are some test online, maybe you check it out, before saying python is slow... https://blog.thedataincubator.com/2018/05/sqlite-vs-pandas-performance-benchmarks/

Comment: pandas time is only higher for filtering...not for groupby, merge what is also provided in the link

Comment: yes you're right, sorry, i didn't realise the graph is showing different things. it appears to be so with this test in the article. i have done some quick logging of time on my process if done in pandas and i estimate it'd take +15 days which made me think SQLite could be quicker, on the basis that SQL generally is built to megre/join and deal  with big data. Anw, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

> i've read that i can create the function within sqlite3 in python, but i have no idea how.

That's `conn.create_function()`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function

```
>>> import math
>>> conn.create_function('EXP', 1, math.exp)
>>> cur.execute('select EXP(1)')
>>> cur.fetchone()
(2.718281828459045,)
```